# Why does mysqldump need to be fully pathed when called from a controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, mysql

When I call `mysqldump` from a controller or model I need to fully path the binary, when I call it from Rake I don't need to.

If I do not fully path I get a zero byte file...

I can confirm both processes are run using the same user.

```
# Works in a controller, model and Rake task
system "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root #{w.database_name} > #{target_file}"

# Only works in a Rake task
system "mysqldump -u root #{w.database_name} > #{target_file}"
```

If I call the Rake task from the action it also fails (zero byte file).

OS: Mac
Ruby 1.8.6

EDIT: I use `Etc.getpwuid(Process.uid).name` to get the User of the current process

Comment: How do you run your Rails app? I think you should check that the process running it has the same environment (along with PATH variable) as when you run Rake.

Comment: The process is running under the same user, I am not so sure about what the PATH is set to in both cases.

Comment: In Rails ENV['PATH'] is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
In Rake ENV['PATH'] it is exactly the same as my system $PATH.
Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always modify your PATH environment variable as required, of course. Something like this is best done in environment.rb or your specific environment config:

```
add_paths = %w[ /usr/local/mysql/bin /opt/local/bin ]
ENV['PATH'] = (ENV['PATH'].split(/:/) + add_paths).uniq.select do |p|
  File.exist?(File.expand_path(p))
end.join(':')
```

This way you can add arbitrary elements to your path if they exist on your system.

Comment: Would this suggest that the Ruby ENV['PATH'] is independent from the system $PATH?

Comment: Any shells you create inherit the environment of the ruby process, just as ruby inherits from the parent shell. It's not independent, but  inherited from the system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out Passenger (mod_rails) does not run in a shell like Mongrel, which is obvious when you think about it. Therefore it does *not* 'inherit' the full system $PATH.